# Datatables, export buttons not showing with ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with export buttons on datatables.
I build a table with datatables and the table is loading after chosing a data from select field in a form.
the problem is the export buttons (Excel, pdf) don't showing.

### libraries

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha512-yDlE7vpGDP7o2eftkCiPZ+yuUyEcaBwoJoIhdXv71KZWugFqEphIS3PU60lEkFaz8RxaVsMpSvQxMBaKVwA5xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.1/b-2.3.3/b-html5-2.3.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

### HTML

#### form for sending filters

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return false" id="allTiming" action="">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-1">
      <label class="col-form-label" for="date_debut">Date début</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      <input class="form-control" id="date_emb" name="date_debut" type="date"  placeholder="Date debut" aria-label="Date debut">
     </div>
     <div class="col-1">
       <label class="col-form-label" for="date_debut">Date fin</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col">
       <input class="form-control" id="date_emb" name="date_fin" type="date"  placeholder="Date fin" aria-label="Date fin">
     </div>

     <div class="col">
      <button type="submit" id="submitAllHist" name="btn_rechercher" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

#### Table

```
<table id="allAffect" class="table table-bordered table-striped datatable table table-resposive">
    <thead>
    <tr style="font-size:12px;background: #716aca;color:white;">
        <th>Matricule</th>
        <th>Nom & Prenoms</th>
        <th>Contat</th>
        <th>Activité</th>
        <th>Superviseur</th>
        <th>Vehicule</th>
        <th>Date affectation</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="listDyn">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Datatable ith Ajax Source

```
$("#RiList").DataTable( {
        destroy: true,

       dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel',
            'csv'
        ],

        ajax:{
           url: './main/treatment.php?action=list&param='+param,
           dataSrc: ''
        },

       columns: [
           {data: 'matricule'},
           {data: 'nom'},
           {data: 'contact'},
           {data: 'activite'},
           {data: 'immatriculation'},
           {data: 'date'}
       ],

    } );
```

I failed to show Export Buttons (CSV, Excel) when the datatable is initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

If you are using Ajax for your datatable sources like me,
you must declare the dom and the button after ajax call.
it is why export buttons did not show.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment, so I write an answer.
I made a test and I comment (//)  the `dom: 'Bfrtip'` as you.
So the buttons don't showing.
I remove the comment tags (// ) and it is ok.

Please remove the comment tags ( // ) from your code at `dom: 'Bfrtip` and test

Comment: This is the example I used 
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: it was a mistake.
dom: 'Bfrtip' is not comment in my code.

Comment: @Mussa Have you added the javascript library files, mentioned in the exemple ?

Comment: @SelVazi yes i have added jquery library before datatables

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't include all the required Js files.

In addition of jquery.js and datatables.js, those are required for buttons copy and csv :

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Nb : orders should be respected, `jquery` first then `datatables` then buttons js files.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        destroy: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv'
        ]
    } );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>Y</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: before update data from ajax sources, i met any problems. It's just when i tried to put filter form that problems appears